# 500px.com layout

Tags: css, layout

I was wondering if anyone knows how this type of layout works

http://500px.com/

Or maybe this is a better example

http://500px.com/leventi/flow

I was wondering how they get the layout working on the fly. I don't think they have a front end dev putting these individual in, and all box sizes are unique (and fit very nicely) if anyone would offer me guidance or a link to any articles showing how this can be done, much apreicated!

Comment: You can have a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Comment: Nothing to do with masonry as all boxes have defined height on 500px. In the opposite and that the main point about masonry, it helps you to get a consistent view with elements having random heights. 500px is more a various but accurate defined setup of differents widths and heights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use column based layouts check out this:

- http://960.gs/

alternativey would be Twitter Bootstrap which provides fluid and fixed layouts:

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

For flowing items around consider this, which is an jQuery plugin:

- http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

For the **downvote** any reasons ?